# Installing Linux on HP Alpha ES 45 servers

Tags: linux, debian

Does any one know whether Debian can be installed on HP Alpha ES 45 servers. I checked the Debian website. But there was no option to download Debian for alpha architecture. Or do you know any other Linux distribution that has a release for Alpha CPUs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to have a look at the [**Debian Alpha Port**](http://www.debian.org/ports/alpha/) pages which suggest that the ES45 will run at least some versions. The installation manual is [**here**](http://www.debian.org/releases/stable/alpha/) and you can download the binaries from the [**Debian mirrors**](http://www.debian.org/mirror/list)

Comment: Rats! I knew I should've asked for the old AlphaServer 4/275 we had in a corner when I left my last job.

Answer (score 0):

its listed under support by linux 
http://www.debian.org/ports/alpha/sys_types
good luck :)